# Linux Browsers And VBScript

Tags: linux, vbscript, cross-browser, portability, platform-independent

I've already done some little things using Visual Basic and some nice things with eMbedded Visual Basic, but now I want to go on the scripting way, then I want to know if Linux, BeOS and other OSes browsers will support VBScript pages.

Comment: Just to make sure, do you mean client-side or server-side scripting?

Answer (score 6):

VBScript is supported only by Internet Explorer. The only scripting language supported by other browsers (even on Windows) is JavaScript.

You can either rewrite your scripts to JavaScript or write VB interpreter in JavaScript **;)**

Comment: Any way to use it with Firefox(atleast) on Linux?

Comment: I don't know of anything like that.

Comment: Other scripting languages can be supported with plugins (e.g. http://www.tcl.tk/software/plugin/), though Javascript is the only one that's generally supported out-of-the-box (and even it varies slightly across browsers). As far as I can tell, there's no VBScript plugin for Firefox.